# Reverse list in Apex

Tags: apex, list

Can you reverse a list of objects in Apex?

In Java and C#, there is a method you can call to reverse a list but I don't see one for Apex...

Comment: Theres no native method for reversing a list in apex. [Related Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134327/reverse-the-order-of-map-in-apex-or-vf/134333)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No such method currently exists on the `List` class as of Winter '17 (API v38). The only way to do this in Apex that I'm aware of is to loop over the list starting from the end.

```
List<Object> someList = new List<Object>{1,2,3,4,5};
List<Object> reversed = new List<Object>();

for(Integer i = someList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    reversed.add(somelist[i]);
}
```

If you're storing instances of an Apex class in a list, you could over-engineer a solution by using the strategy pattern and implementing the [Comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm#apex_comparable) so you can use the `sort()` method with different sort orders.

A crude example

```
public class IntWrapper implements Comparable{
    public Integer int;
    public static String order = 'ASC';
    
    public IntWrapper(Integer val){
        int = val;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object input){
        Integer result;
        if(IntWrapper.order == 'ASC'){
            result = compareASC(input);
        } else {
            result = compareDESC(input);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Integer compareASC(Object input){
        Integer intIn = (Integer)input;
        if(int < intIn){
            return -1;
        } else if(int > intIn){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private Integer compareDESC(Object input){
        Integer intIn = (Integer)input;
        if(int < intIn){
            return 1;
        } else if(int > intIn){
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

List<IntWrapper> someList = new List<IntWrapper>{new IntWrapper(1), new IntWrapper(2), new IntWrapper(3), new IntWrapper(4), new IntWrapper(5)};

// First sort ensures we're in ASC order
someList.sort();

// Set the static flag, sort again, et voila, list is reversed
IntWrapper.order = 'DESC';
someList.sort();
```

Reversing insertion order like this is possible, but you'd need an extra integer in your class to hold the list index, and something like an `addToList(someList)` method that would set the list index to `someList.size()` before adding it to the list.

### +edit:

This general method, having a wrapper class that implements `Comparable`, can also be used for defining custom sort orders for `sObjects` as well. There's even [supporting documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

Comment: There is one extra minus sign in the for loop. :)
It seems like the second solution is dependent on that the objects have some order to them. Would it work for a general solution where you just have a bunch of objects and you just want to flip the list?

Comment: Indeed there is. Seems like my keyboard liked to type a bunch of extra characters today. Answer edited.

Comment: As for "just flip the list", I did make a note about that towards the bottom of my answer (regarding insertion order). You'd still need a wrapper class, with an `Integer` (let's call it `order`) to track the insertion order into the list. You wouldn't be able to simply add something to the list with `list.add()`, you'd need to write a method in the wrapper class (passing your target list as an argument) to set `order` and then insert into the list you passed as an argument.

Comment: Honestly, just iterating backwards over the list in a loop is probably the simplest and fastest solution here. I just like working out these types of problems as programming exercises.

Comment: A for loop going backwards is undoubtedly the easiest. I am curious as to why Salesforce hasn't implemented a reverse list method.

Comment: If I had to guess (since Apex is compiled to Java bytecode, [ref 1](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69342/does-apex-transpile-into-java), [ref 2](https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/salesforces-apex-runtime-design-old-vs-new)), I'd say it's because there probably isn't a good way for Salesforce to use Java's `Collections.reverse(List<?>)` with how I suspect they've implemented Lists in Apex.

Answer (score 10):

Just for completeness, you could also implement a [custom reverse iterator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) :

```
public class ReverseIterator implements Iterator<Object>
{
    public List<Object> internalRef;
    integer position;
    public ReverseIterator(List<Object> source)
    {
        internalRef = source;
        position = internalRef.size();
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return position > 0;
    }

    public Object next()
    {
        return internalRef[--position];
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
ReverseIterator revIt = new ReverseIterator(new List<Object>{1, 2, 3});
while (revIt.hasNext())
{
    Integer current = (integer)revIt.next();
    System.debug(current);
}
```

At the moment, you can't use these in `for` loops, which limits the usefulness of actually implementing the interface, but perhaps in the future `for` loop support will be added to the interface.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a neat solution and can work across whatever object I have in the list. This is just a tad more complicated.

Comment: @akcorp2003 Yeah, it would really shine if you could wrap it in a factory method and use it in a `for` loop like `for(object i : reverseTraverse(myList))`.  One other use would be that you can create methods that take iterators and perform some set of operations on them, like LINQ extensions in C#.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "reverse" method in list, see all available methods: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm%23apex_methods_system_list

I guess you must create a new List and iterate over your existing list backwards populating the new one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]What about using a for loop and iterating in reverse?

```
Integer[] myInts = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
for (Integer i = myInts.size()-1; i>= 0; i-- ) {
   System.debug('myInts[' + i + '] = ' + myInts[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the accepted answer suggests to create yet another list. Why not swap elements?

```
Integer n = someList.size();
for(Integer i=0, half=n>>1; i < half; i++) {
// or if you wish:
// for(Integer i=0; i < n/2; i++) {
    Object o = someList[i];
    someList[i] = someList[n-i-1];
    someList[n-i-1] = o;
}
```

An [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) reversion not only needs much less memory, it should also be faster. In the context of Apex it's often worthwhile to have a look how things are done in Java - e.g. have a look [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l374).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last element of a list created by a split in one line you can cheat a little:

```
System.debug('first/middle/last'.reverse().split('/').get(0).reverse());
```

This will get you the last element. You could also join a list before performing this magic trick.